# Why am I seeing this in /var/log?

Tags: logging, system-compromise, indicator-of-compromise

I've noticed a lot of weird logs in `/var/log` on my server.

For example:

```
cd /var/log/DIST00000001ARGC00000005ARGV00000002ccARGV00000002-cARGV00000006nmap.cARGV00000002-oARGV00000006nmap.oDOTI00000000
sudo cat user.log 
Jun 30 16:48:08 DIST00000001ARGC00000005ARGV00000002ccARGV00000002-cARGV00000006nmap.cARGV00000002-oARGV00000006nmap.oDOTI00000000
```

Another example:

```
cd /var/log/Nmap
sudo cat user.log 
Jun 30 16:48:28 Nmap
```

Note Nmap is not installed on my server.

Another example:

```
cd get_info
sudo cat user.log
Jun 30 16:48:25 get_info
```

I'm worried this may be a sign my server has been compromised, but perhaps it's something else?

The server is `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-77-generic x86_64)` with unattended-upgrades turned on for security updates.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file for some ideas around how to find how these files are being created.

Comment: Try putting the contents of netstat -tulpn in here (you can and should censor some of the sensitive stuff you see there if there is any)

Comment: @Stiofán, what's your server's Internet connectivity like? What is it usually in contact with?

Comment: *The server is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS* is no enough! You seem to have something able to create *logdir* under `/var/log` (wich require special rights). Could you list what's running on this server, and describe the kind of services your server do offer...

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a 100% 'answer' but getting to the next step -- maybe strings sent by an nmap service probe?

https://svn.nmap.org/!svn/bc/3320/nmap/nmap-service-probes

Comment: Thanks @paal527569 I think you're right. Seems odd the probes are getting their own log files though. I guess there must be something installed on the server which is logging this stuff.

Comment: @Stiofán do you have anything listening on port 3632?